# reduce a panda dataframe by groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've been searching extensively but can't get my head around this issue:

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like this:

```
date    ticker Name NoShares SharePrice Volume Relation
2/1/10  aaa    zzz  1        1          1      d 
2/1/10  aaa    yyy  1        2          5      o
2/1/10  aaa    zzz  2        5          2      d  
2/5/10  bbb    xxx  5        5          1      do
2/5/10  ccc    www  5        5          1      d
2/5/10  ccc    www  5        5          1      d
2/5/10  ddd    vvv  5        5          1      o
2/6/10  aaa    zzz  1        1          3      d
```

Requirements

1. I want to group by date and Name and:
2. have the number of shares summed up
3. have a weighted mean column for the share price (the weights are the NoShares)
4. average the volume and have it as a column
5. Leave relation as it is

so my output would look like this:

```
date    ticker Name NoShares SharePrice Volume Relation
2/1/10  aaa    zzz  3        3.6        1      d 
2/1/10  aaa    yyy  1        2          5      o
2/5/10  bbb    xxx  5        5          1      do
2/5/10  ccc    www  10       5          1      d
2/5/10  ddd    vvv  5        5          1      o
2/6/10  aaa    zzz  1        1          3      d
```

I tried the documentation and other answers on stack overflow but don't seem to be able to get it right. Appreciate the help. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's my solution:

```
grpby = df.groupby(['date','Name'])
a = grpby.apply(lambda x: np.average(a = x['SharePrice'],weights=x['NoShares'])).to_frame(name='SharePrice')
b = grpby.agg({'NoShares':'sum','Volume':'mean','Relation':'max'})
print b.join(a)

             Volume Relation  NoShares  SharePrice
date   Name                                       
2/1/10 yyy   5.0000        o         1      2.0000
       zzz   1.5000        d         3      3.6667
2/5/10 vvv   1.0000        o         5      5.0000
       www   1.0000        d        10      5.0000
       xxx   1.0000       do         5      5.0000
2/6/10 zzz   3.0000        d         1      1.0000
```

just reset_index() afterwards.

Comment: You can skip join and directly aggregate after creating a lambda:  `weigted_mean = lambda x: np.average(x, weights=tdf.loc[x.index, "NoShares"])
    tdf.groupby(['date','Name']).agg({'NoShares':'sum','SharePrice': weigted_mean, 'Volume': 'mean'}).reset_index()`

Comment: Nice technique to allow this to all occur within one .agg() call. Mindful that it creates a coupling to tdf.

Comment: Thanks. Answer was well explained and very helpful (of course solving my problem exactly).

Answer (score 0):

I made an assumption here. When you said group by date and Name and to keep relation - I am assuming that ticker and relation will also be unique to those groups. So for simplicity I am grouping by all 4.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
                ['2/1/10', 'aaa', 'zzz', 1, 1, 1, 'd'], 
                ['2/1/10', 'aaa', 'yyy', 1, 2, 5, 'o'],
                ['2/1/10', 'aaa', 'zzz', 2, 5, 2, 'd'],  
                ['2/5/10', 'bbb', 'xxx', 5, 5, 1, 'do'],
                ['2/5/10', 'ccc', 'www', 5, 5, 1, 'd'],
                ['2/5/10', 'ccc', 'www', 5, 5, 1, 'd'],
                ['2/5/10', 'ddd', 'vvv', 5, 5, 1, 'o'],
                ['2/6/10', 'aaa', 'zzz', 1, 1, 3, 'd']],
             columns = ['date', 'ticker', 'Name', 'NoShares',
                        'SharePrice', 'Volume', 'Relation'])

def process_date(dg):
    return pd.DataFrame([[
                        dg['NoShares'].sum(),
                        (dg['NoShares'] * dg['SharePrice']).sum() / dg['NoShares'].sum(),
                        dg['Volume'].mean(),
                        ]], columns=['NoShares', 'SharePrice', 'Volume'])

df.groupby(['date', 'ticker', 'Name', 'Relation']).apply(process_date).reset_index(4, drop=True).reset_index(drop=False)
```

Results:

```
     date ticker Name Relation  NoShares  SharePrice  Volume
0  2/1/10    aaa  yyy        o         1    2.000000     5.0
1  2/1/10    aaa  zzz        d         3    3.666667     1.5
2  2/5/10    bbb  xxx       do         5    5.000000     1.0
3  2/5/10    ccc  www        d        10    5.000000     1.0
4  2/5/10    ddd  vvv        o         5    5.000000     1.0
5  2/6/10    aaa  zzz        d         1    1.000000     3.0
```

Comment: Thank you. Would have also marked this as accepted answer if I could. Your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Both Dickster's and Leo's answers work well but just be aware that `.groupby` has `dropna=True` set by default. So if you have a dataset and perform `groupby` on multiple columns where some of those columns might contain `NaN's` Pandas will drop these groups. The final `DataFrame` will have less rows then.

The same SQL query on a SQL Server don't drop rows with NULL values in columns that are in a group by clause. I don't know if that's true for other RDBMS but just bear in mind that Pandas by default treat `group by` in a different way.